# nexus-2.14.5-02 shows Connect to repository.apache.org:443 [repository.apache.org/207.244.88.140] failed: connect timed out In Running mode

Tags: repository

After starting up nexus shows below warning and while accessing port 8081, it shows `HTTP ERROR: 404`. Please guide.

```
jvm 1    | 2019-06-26 02:35:38,236-0400 INFO  [pxpool-1-thread-1] *TASK org.sonatype.nexus.index.NexusScanningListener - Scanning of repositoryID="central" finished: scanned=0, added=0, updated=0, removed=0, scanningDuration=0:00:00.123
jvm 1    | 2019-06-26 02:35:38,237-0400 INFO  [pxpool-1-thread-1] *TASK org.sonatype.nexus.index.DefaultIndexerManager - Publishing index for repository central
jvm 1    | 2019-06-26 02:35:38,263-0400 INFO  [pxpool-1-thread-1] *TASK org.sonatype.nexus.index.DefaultIndexerManager - Publishing index for repository public
jvm 1    | 2019-06-26 02:35:38,293-0400 INFO  [pxpool-1-thread-1] *TASK org.sonatype.nexus.index.tasks.UpdateIndexTask - Scheduled task (UpdateIndexTask) finished :: Updating repository index "Public Repositories" from path null and below. (started 2019-06-26T02:35:37-04:00, runtime 0:00:00.693)
jvm 1    | 2019-06-26 02:35:38,504-0400 INFO  [pxpool-1-thread-1] *TASK org.sonatype.nexus.configuration.application.DefaultNexusConfiguration - Applying Nexus Configuration due to changes in [Scheduled Tasks] made by *TASK...
jvm 1    | 2019-06-26 02:35:38,805-0400 INFO  [jetty-main-1]  org.sonatype.nexus.webresources.internal.WebResourceServiceImpl - Discovered 1971 resources
jvm 1    | 2019-06-26 02:35:38,806-0400 INFO  [jetty-main-1]  org.sonatype.nexus.webresources.internal.WebResourceServlet - Max-age: 30 days (2592000 seconds)
jvm 1    | 2019-06-26 02:35:38,830-0400 INFO  [jetty-main-1]  org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.InstrumentedSelectChannelConnector - Metrics enabled
jvm 1    | 2019-06-26 02:35:38,844-0400 INFO  [jetty-main-1]  org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Started InstrumentedSelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8081
jvm 1    | 2019-06-26 02:35:38,844-0400 INFO  [jetty-main-1]  org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer - Running
jvm 1    | 2019-06-26 02:35:38,844-0400 INFO  [WrapperListener_start_runner]  org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer - Started
jvm 1    | 2019-06-26 02:35:57,818-0400 WARN  [ar-4-thread-3] *TASK org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.maven.routing.internal.RemoteContentDiscovererImpl - Remote strategy prefix-file error on M2Repository(id=apache-snapshots): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to repository.apache.org:443 [repository.apache.org/207.244.88.140] failed: connect timed out
jvm 1    | 2019-06-26 02:35:57,881-0400 WARN  [ar-4-thread-2] *TASK org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.maven.routing.internal.RemoteContentDiscovererImpl - Remote strategy prefix-file error on M2Repository(id=central): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to repo1.maven.org:443 [repo1.maven.org/151.101.184.209] failed: connect timed out
```

Also tried adding below line 
inside `nexus.properties` file:

```
org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.maven.routing.Config.prefixFileMaxSize=500000
```

It didn't help.

Comment: Welcome to superuser! It is unknown what you are asking - you need to provide a specific question so we can answer it. We do not provide guidance.

Comment: After nexus-2.14.5-02 repository installation, i tried starting nexus, it started with above warning. While accessing nexus url localhost:8081 I am getting HTTP ERROR: 404.

Comment: Can you contact repo1.maven.org via your server?  It seems there is a timeout (which would result in a 404 on call).